# I can't play html audio with muted attribute in ios14.2 safari

Tags: javascript, html, ios, safari, html5-audio

Audio plays well with the muted attribute in versions below ios 14.2. (In muted state, but time of music continues.)

However, since iOS 14.2, audio has been acting strangely. If audio is played with the muted attribute applied, the audio stops immediately. if the audio is played again, it stops immediately and the audio duration is distorted. ( like 0.0006 )

Is there anyone who knows why?

I attach jsfiddle. ( Testing in ios 14.2 can check issue )

```html
<div>
  <div>* Mp3</div>
  <audio onplay="onPlayHandler()" id="audio" 
 src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/transcoded/d/de/Lorem_ipsum.ogg/Lorem_ipsum.ogg.mp3" muted="true" controls="true"></audio>
  <button onclick="mutedAudio()">toggle muted</button>
  <div>
    <br/>
    * isMuted : <span id="muted_state">true</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    * audioDuration(update when play audio) : <span id="duration"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BangKyungmin/42mwdgqv/42/)

**First time played with muted(stop immediately)**
[image: First time]

**Second time played with muted(also stop immediately. Please check audio duration)**
[image]

Comment: Sounds like a bug you should [file with the Webkit team](https://webkit.org/reporting-bugs/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted bug report at webkit bugzilla and received answer.

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=219295#c5